# Copying data from multiple tabs to DIFFERENT files

Tags: vba, excel

Good day,

I have 2 excel files I'm using right now:

1) A main file where sales of agents per day for 31 days are calculated, each agent on a different sheet, which range from sheet#1-100 and a sheet called TOTAL which shows the totals for all the sheets and some other calculations which aren't relevant for this question.

2) An invoice file which has a sheet where I copy the data for that specific agent from file#1, this is the main part of the invoice. There are other sheets as well but they are all dependant on the invoice sheet, so they shouldn't really be relevant.

The invoice is built in such a way that I copy the name, site and the amounts from #1 to the invoice, than check if all the stuff I copied are correct, if they are I print the invoice and use a macro to save it under the invoice number(say xxx) than it deletes the data I just copied and adds +1 to the invoice number(new invoice number will than be xxx+1)

There are usually around 100 invoices that I manually need to copy and paste and check everything. My question is that is there a way to make this process automatic?
As in activate a VBA code that goes to file#1-sheet#1,copies the relevant data to the invoice, prints it out and than uses the same macro i use to save it so that the invoices number rises by 1 and than goes to file#1-sheet#2 etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of code to copy a range from one workbook to another:

```
Sub CopyRange()

    Dim strPath As String  'Path to invoice file
    Dim wbk1 As Workbook   'Used for file#1
    Dim wbk2 As Workbook   'Used for file#2
    Dim agent_num As Integer  'Can store the number

    strPath = "C:\wherever your invoice file is"

    Set wbk1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(strPath)

    While (agent_num <= wbk1.Sheets.Count())  
        'copy a range - repeat as necessary
        wbk2.Worksheets("Name of invoice sheet").Range("Where you are copying to").Value = wbk1.Worksheets(agent_num).Range("Where you are copying from").Value
        'Save that invoice file how you want it
        'Then increase the invoice number by 1
        'Set those cells back to ""
        wbk2.Worksheets("Name of invoice sheet").Range("Where you are copying to").Value = ""
        agent_num++  'next sheet
    Loop

    wbk2.Close()

End Sub
```

You will need to edit a few things for your purposes, but I think it should work. Sorry if I have made any mistakes, I have been unable to test it